# Tag renaming from plugin-reccomendation to plugin-rec

Tags: discussion

Like it has already done on other stack sites with `webapp-rec` and `game-rec` I would like to suggest use `plugin-rec` instead of long form `plugin-reccomendation`.

What do you think?

Comment: Each time I read rec I think recording. Probably in remembrance to old audio cassette decks.

Answer (score 4):

I think one thing to consider is why would we use `plugin-rec` over `plugin-recommendation`? Because it's been used on other sites? I would argue that we are an individual community and that we should not simply be following what other sites have done because it has 'already been done'.

`plugin-recommendation` instantly tells users what the question is tagged as, and therefore what the question is likely to be asking, even without a title, whereas if you're not a regular user of the site `plugin-rec` does not.

I think we should use the longer form, technically there's nothing wrong with it, and the meaning of it is much more obvious.

Comment: +1 I also started the [tag wiki](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tags/plugin-recommendation/info) for plugin-recommendation.  If anyone has anything to add please do.

Answer (score 3):

There was [a discussion about this on the WebApps Meta](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54/should-rec-tags-be-added), and the participants there are not in favor of this format. They prefer to split the tag up, so `[plugin-rec]` would become `[plugins] [recommendation]`. The meaning of `-rec` is not obvious to everybody, and both parts have a meaning independent of each other, so they don't need to be combined in one tag (unlike `[windows-7]` for example, which should not be split into `[windows] [7]`).